# Awk is inserting whitespace

Tags: bash, scripting, awk

I am trying to swap two columns in a csv file and I'm using this:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

BEGIN {FS="$\t"}
{temp=$1; $1=$2; $2=temp}{print$0}
```

Which works great, except it's adding an extra whitespace at the beginning of the line. How can I prevent this?

My input file looks like this

```
1\t2
3\t4
```

What I get looks like this:

```
 2\t1
 3\t4
```

Comment: can you show your input file?

Comment: Why not just `BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"} {print $2,$1}`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

why you have the dollar in your `FS`?

I don't think your current `FS` even work. ... remove the `$`, and it should be ok.

**for the reason of the leading empty:**

with your current FS, `$\t` means a tab after the end of line. which will match nothing. that is, after processed by awk, each line of your file has only one field. There is only `$0 and $1` there is no `$2` at all. so $2 is empty.

you did the swap, actually you just add an empty field to your original line. And because you reset a field ($1 and $2), when you print $0, awk will apply OFS on the line, in your case, OFS is default, a space. so, awk will print:

```
$2<space>$1
```

keep in mind, $2 is empty and $1 is actually your $0.

Answer (score 2):

It's caused by setting the `FS` to the wrong value.

You want `FS="\t"`.